# How to change profile pic and server name using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to change the profile picture of a server, change the server name and deleting all channels with one command.

At the moment, the command is `test` and it can delete all channels, but I want that `test` command to change the profile picture and the server name as well.

How can i do this?

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
console.log('charging duh...')
client.once('Loading...', () => {
  console.log('Loading...');
});
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content === `${prefix}lol`) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 13000; i++) {
      message.channel.send('<@632899988011220992>');
    }
  } else if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
      channel.delete();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), you can change the guild icon with [`.setIcon`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=setIcon) and the servername with [`.setName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=setName).

Answer (score 0):

For v12 users it is:

`user.displayAvatarURL()`